# How to get post links from the whole page using BeautifulSoup Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble trying to web scraping using BeautifulSoup and Selenium. The problem I have is i want to try pulling data from pages 1-20. But somehow the data that was successfully pulled was only up to page 10. It is possible that the number of the last page limit that I would take could be more than 20, but the results of the code I made could only pull 10 pages. Does anyone have an understanding for the problem to be able to pull a lot of data without page limit?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

apartment_urls = []

try:
   for page in range(1,20):
       print(f"Extraction Page# {page}")
       page="https://www.99.co/id/sewa/apartemen/jakarta?kamar_tidur_min=1&kamar_tidur_maks=4&kamar_mandi_min=1&kamar_mandi_maks=4&tipe_sewa=bulanan&hlmn=" + str(page) 
       driver.get(page)  
       time.sleep(5)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
       apart_info_list = soup.select('h2.search-card-redesign__address a[href]')
       for link in apart_info_list:
           get_url = '{0}{1}'.format('https://www.99.co', link['href'])
           print(get_url)
           apartment_urls.append(get_url)

except:
   print("Good Bye!")
```

This is the output of the code. When pages 10,11,12 and so on I can't get the data
[image: Output Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, pagination is working fine without page limit.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.99.co/id/sewa/apartemen/jakarta?kamar_tidur_min=1&kamar_tidur_maks=4&kamar_mandi_min=1&kamar_mandi_maks=4&tipe_sewa=bulanan')
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    apart_info_list = soup.select('h2.search-card-redesign__address a')
    for link in apart_info_list:
        get_url = '{0}{1}'.format('https://www.99.co', link['href'])
        print(get_url)

    next_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.next > a ')
    if next_button:
        button = next_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

    else:
        break
```

If you would prefer to use: [webdriverManager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Alternative solution: As the next page url isn't dynamic, It's also working fine.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.99.co/id/sewa/apartemen/jakarta?kamar_tidur_min=1&kamar_tidur_maks=4&kamar_mandi_min=1&kamar_mandi_maks=4&tipe_sewa=bulanan')
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    apart_info_list = soup.select('h2.search-card-redesign__address a')
    for link in apart_info_list:
        get_url = '{0}{1}'.format('https://www.99.co', link['href'])
        print(get_url)

    # next_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.next > a ')
    # if next_button:
    #     button = next_button.click()
    #     time.sleep(3)

    next_page = soup.select_one('li.next > a ')
    if next_page:
        next_page = f'https://www.99.co{next_page}'
       
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I have tried but errors like this ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (596, 6575)
  (Session info: headless chrome=101.0.4951.64)

Comment: But I'm not getting any issue.The url is under cloudflare protection. Use driver in normal mode not headless mode.

Comment: OR you can imitate my complete way

Comment: I tried implementing it with google colab for the web driver manager, is it correct to install like this link https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: Firstly, you have to  install selenium4: pip install selenium4 then pip install webdriver-manager and after all: # selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

Comment: Actually, I'm not so much familiar with google colab. I'm using vscode

Comment: Wait a second i'll try it

Comment: Thank you, it's work. i have tried it on vscode